# How deep can discounts on Amazon get?

Tags: shopping

I'm looking at the Hogwart Train set on Amazon right now and they are 20% off the MSRP. I recently bought the 60198 set at a 5% discount, now it is 16% off.

I wanted to know typically how deep the discounts can go and how far into a release do they start discounting and how quickly they sell out.

Can people who have a lot of buying experience on Amazon comment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this is one of those things I assume everyone already knows about, similar to complaints about too many or too long *YouTube* commercials.  Everyone knows about *Adblockers* and how a mere 32 second web browser install/restart can nix out a lifetime of meaningless commercial watching.

So, how about online buying? How do I know I'm getting the best deal on *Amazon.com*?

**TRUST ME**: 
It'll take you longer to read this than to get the results you're looking for *ALL FOR FREE!*

- Go to [*CamelCamelCamel.com*](https://camelcamelcamel.com/).
- In the search field type in the word *"LEGO + SET Number or KEY WORD"*.
- Hit "*Enter/Return*".

**WHAT'CHA GET:**

- *CCC* price tracks ANY ITEM on Amazon.com.
- From the lowest price EVER by date.
- To the highest EVER by date.
- FOR FREE.
- Allows you to set in a price alert (free by email) when an item's price falls to an
  entered amount, or by an entered percentage off.
- Again, ALL FOR FREE.

**BOTH YOUR EXAMPLES:**

- *Example 01*:  Search "LEGO Hogwarts Train":
- *Example 02*: Search "LEGO 60198". (last picture.)

[image]

- List of potential items with that name to click further on to see its
  price history.

[image]

- After you zeroed in on the item you want *CCC* shows a price history
  graph.  Gives options to get email alerts when the price hits certain
  threshold on either Amazon or 3rd Party sellers.

[image]

**FINAL SAY:**
I don't know why more people aren't using this it's free and it's not really a secret it must the its silly name that throws folks off...

**EXTRA CREDIT:**
There's another *Amazon Price Tracker* named [*KEEPA*](https://keepa.com/#!), but I've never used it.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As a general practise discount can be quite big (I've seen -50% off) for a small set and tend to be much lower (around -25% off) for a large set.

Discounts tend to vary even during the same day. So it is worth keeping an eye. Some sites, like Brickset tend to announce LEGO sales too. They even have a [tracker](https://brickset.com/buy) for Amazon and other services. I suggest to look here to have a sense of understanding how much discounted the set can get.

Comment: I picked up the Heartlake Cupcake Store for $8 on Amazon.com last year (RRP $40). That’s an 80% discount. Amazon was the seller.

Often those extreme discounts last only a few minutes, an hour or two tops though.

Comment: It can help to clear your browser cookies, or open an incognito window and search for the same set. I've seen prices tailored just for me. Sometimes they're more expensive; sometimes they're cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

I've watched the [the BrickSet Amazon.com notices](https://brickset.com/news/category-Amazon-com-watch) for the last year or so.  Most of the discounts are in the 20-35% range, but sometimes they get up to 50% off for $9.99 sets.  If you're on [BrickSet](https://brickset.com/) all of the time anyway it is easy to setup your news feed to include these.  When I see one come up I click on any that might seem interesting.  So far the discounted sets have been for things I haven't cared about.  Based on that I expect I will find something that I want to buy 10x of for parting out before I find a set that I want for the set itself.